# Help! How to Transfer ERC20 TOKENS from a WALLET CONTRACT (Mist) to a Normal Address

Tags: solidity, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Since Mist wallet no longer works, at all, I am trying to retrieve my tokens from the WALLET CONTRACT which can be natively created by Mist (not multisig). I can't recall why I set this up but I think it was recommended by the foundation for some reason so thats where I kept them.

I have tried using other platforms like mycrypto and myetherwallet but when interacting with the contract it only offers the basic functions like 'kill' which will kill the wallet contract but only transfer the Ether, not the tokens.

I have checked google and pretty much no one has the same problem as me. Does anyone know how I can do this whether it's via an online or desktop wallet? Or even using a script if it's possible?

In the final screenshot, this is what happens when I try to write the transaction on the OMG account, it fails with an rpc error. My plan was to take the transaction data from this to then execute in the account that holds the wallet contract.

Thanks

P

[image]

[image]

[image: This is what happens when I try to write the transaction on the OMG account, it fails with an rpc error]

Comment: Are you sure it's a contract and not an external account? Can you post its address so we know for sure which one it is?

Comment: Perhaps you created a multisig with a single owner. In that case you can call `execute()` like `execute(<token_addres>, 0, <transfer_data>)` where `<transfer_data>` is the token transfer operation encoded in solidity ABI.

Comment: This is the wallet contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0x9cdafa6942ec9cd1657e204560496b8bdb4ae6ca#tokentxns

Comment: The wallet contract above was created by this normal address/account which you generate in Mist: https://etherscan.io/address/0x9f2477c4121c15e25d7b7084e6fa5f0aa65357cc

Comment: I added some screenshots from the web-based testnet platform. I simply gave a name, clicked on 'ADD WALLET CONTRACT' and 'SINGLE OWNER ACCOUNT' then clicked create. Thats how the wallet contract was created.

Comment: I managed to connect my web3 (metamask) to etherscan, does anyone know how to do this via etherscan by writing a contract?

Comment: The transaction is failing when I try to write to the OMG token, added screenshot in the description

Answer (score 1):

Checking to see if you made any progress - I have the same issue. I have a cryptopunk stuck in mine. Would be nice to solve this.

Comment: Hello, yes in the end I contacted mycrypto (maarten@mycrypto.com) and they walked me through how to do it with their wallet. 

They were awesome. I tipped them some bitcoin for helping me too, since there was a bit of back and forth. 

Get in touch with them, they were super responsive and super helpful.

Hope this help!